# Flash Pro fails packaging Air app for windows - because of filesize?

Tags: flash, air, package, filesize, windows

I'm developing an Air application for windows with an integrated runtime - the total filesize of all the media assets comes up to ~300MB, and if that's all that I include in the project package, everything goes fine: it publishes successfully in just under a minute or so.

However, as soon as I include the ~2gb folder that contains an executable demo, to be launched from the main app - the publish process takes much much longer, and ultimately fails with the following error message:

[image: Error creating files. Packaging failed. Packager internal error]

This *feels* like a filesize issue to me, but I can't find any documentation that suggests that there would be some kind of hard limit, or a flag to be set somewhere, or anything... all I know is doesn't work if I include those files in the package, and removing them fixes it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that's a size problem, may be the number of files, or just when packaging some kind of files, ..., because I tried to publish a project with 2 big files of 2.5 GB without any problem (except the long time of packaging). But why you don't just zip that big folder and then unzip it using AS3 or an external exe, or even request that to your final user ?

Comment: Putting a .exe in the package is against os security?

Comment: the app is already being distributed as a .zip, so I don't think I'd get much benefit out of putting content inside a nested archive. and the presence of an .exe itself in the package shouldn't be a problem, I've distributed previous versions with .exes before.

Comment: I found the same problem today, and yes it seems like filesize related. I have included 2 .mp4 files in my air settings (Flash CC 2015), total of ~700mb, and if I build the air project with them, I face this same error. If I remove the 500mb mp4 from the list, app is being build without errors. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Nvm, my issue was solved by copy-pasting my media files to app folder and loading them externally from there.